# getting data by name in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

i dont understand how the data i want out of the database

database helper code.java

```
public Cursor getByTitle(String Title){
        String[] args = {Title};

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id,subject,desciption,serverity, lat ,lon FROM main WHERE _id=?",args));
    }

public double getLatitude(Cursor c){return (c.getDouble(6));}

public double getLongitude(Cursor c){return (c.getDouble(7));}
```

activity code.java

```
Cursor c =helper.getByTitle(TitleStr);
        lat=helper.getLatitude(c);
        lon=helper.getLongitude(c);
```

the error is on Cursor c =helper.getByTitle(TitleStr)

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor sp.com.mainTextDBHelper.getByTitle(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at sp.com.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:46)